# Can I ask about tools for collaborating with others?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

My Dad and I sometimes collaborate on solving crosswords. This is a bit difficult when we're not in the same place, unless one of us goes to the trouble of printing a copy. I'd like to ask about tools that we could use to make it easier to collaborate on solving crosswords. Is that on topic on the puzzles stack exchange?